# How to implement a async grpc python server?

Tags: python, grpc

I need to call a celery task for each GRPC request, and return the result.
In default GRPC implementation, each request is processed in a separate thread from a threadpool.

In my case, the server is supposed to process ~400 requests in batch mode per second. So one request may have to wait 1 second for the result due to the batch processing, which means the size of the threadpool must be larger than 400 to avoid blocking.

Can this be done asynchronously?
Thanks a lot.

```
class EventReporting(ss_pb2.BetaEventReportingServicer, ss_pb2.BetaDeviceMgtServicer):
  def ReportEvent(self, request, context):
    res = tasks.add.delay(1,2)
    result = res.get() ->here i have to block
    return ss_pb2.GeneralReply(message='Hello, %s!' % result.message)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done asynchronously if your call to `res.get` can be done asynchronously (if it is defined with the `async` keyword).

[While `grpc.server` says it requires a `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, it will actually work with any `futures.Executor` that calls the behaviors submitted to it on some thread other than the one on which they were passed](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7632). Were you to pass to `grpc.server` a `futures.Executor` implemented by you that only used one thread to carry out four hundred (or more) concurrent calls to `EventReporting.ReportEvent`, your server should avoid the kind of blocking that you describe.

Answer (score 27):

As noted by @Michael in a comment, as of version 1.32, gRPC now supports asyncio in its [Python API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html). If you're using an earlier version, you can still use the asyncio API via the experimental API: `from grpc.experimental import aio`. An asyncio [hello world example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld) has also been added to the gRPC repo. The following code is a copy of the example server:

```
import logging                                                                  
import asyncio                                                                  
from grpc import aio                                                            
                                                                                
import helloworld_pb2                                                           
import helloworld_pb2_grpc                                                      
                                                                                
                                                                                
class Greeter(helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterServicer):                             
                                                                                
    async def SayHello(self, request, context):                                 
        return helloworld_pb2.HelloReply(message='Hello, %s!' % request.name)    
                                                                                
                                                                                
async def serve():                                                              
    server = aio.server()                                                       
    helloworld_pb2_grpc.add_GreeterServicer_to_server(Greeter(), server)        
    listen_addr = '[::]:50051'                                                  
    server.add_insecure_port(listen_addr)                                       
    logging.info("Starting server on %s", listen_addr)                          
    await server.start()                                                        
    await server.wait_for_termination()                                         
                                                                                
                                                                                
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)                                     
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63020695/1510445) for how to implement the client.

Comment: It looks as though this will be moved out of "experimental" in the next release (1.32.0).

Comment: Do you know if streaming works with async api? I'm having some trouble https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092625/grpc-typeerror-unarystreamcall-object-is-not-iterable

Comment: `asyncio.run` in theory is going to create many server objects and keeps going with this.... only `start` is waiting for a client.. isn't ?!

Comment: @Yahya That's incorrect. `asyncio.run` simply runs the one coroutine you give it, in this case the `serve` coroutine. The `serve` coroutine only creates one server, i.e. `server`. `server.start()` runs the server and forces the `serve` coroutine to wait until the server stops, e.g. when `server.stop()` is called. The server can handle simultaneous requests because it uses the asyncio event loop. In short, this code creates a single server that can handle multiple requests because it uses asyncio.

Comment: Both the Client and Server did not work for me, maybe because my system is much more complex than this, so, it kept calling `server.start()` as if it was in a loop. That's why I asked. Thanks anyway for the explanation.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion is good simple implementation async grpc server, same like http based on aiohttp.

```
import asyncio
from concurrent import futures
import functools
import inspect
import threading

from grpc import _server

def _loop_mgr(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):

    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

    # If we reach here, the loop was stopped.
    # We should gather any remaining tasks and finish them.
    pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop=loop)
    if pending:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending))


class AsyncioExecutor(futures.Executor):

    def __init__(self, *, loop=None):

        super().__init__()
        self._shutdown = False
        self._loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=_loop_mgr, args=(self._loop,),
                                        daemon=True)
        self._thread.start()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):

        if self._shutdown:
            raise RuntimeError('Cannot schedule new futures after shutdown')

        if not self._loop.is_running():
            raise RuntimeError("Loop must be started before any function can "
                               "be submitted")

        if inspect.iscoroutinefunction(fn):
            coro = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, self._loop)

        else:
            func = functools.partial(fn, *args, **kwargs)
            return self._loop.run_in_executor(None, func)

    def shutdown(self, wait=True):
        self._loop.stop()
        self._shutdown = True
        if wait:
            self._thread.join()


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #


async def _call_behavior(rpc_event, state, behavior, argument, request_deserializer):
    context = _server._Context(rpc_event, state, request_deserializer)
    try:
        return await behavior(argument, context), True
    except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
        with state.condition:
            if e not in state.rpc_errors:
                details = 'Exception calling application: {}'.format(e)
                _server.logging.exception(details)
                _server._abort(state, rpc_event.operation_call,
                       _server.cygrpc.StatusCode.unknown, _server._common.encode(details))
        return None, False

async def _take_response_from_response_iterator(rpc_event, state, response_iterator):
    try:
        return await response_iterator.__anext__(), True
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        return None, True
    except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
        with state.condition:
            if e not in state.rpc_errors:
                details = 'Exception iterating responses: {}'.format(e)
                _server.logging.exception(details)
                _server._abort(state, rpc_event.operation_call,
                       _server.cygrpc.StatusCode.unknown, _server._common.encode(details))
        return None, False

async def _unary_response_in_pool(rpc_event, state, behavior, argument_thunk,
                                  request_deserializer, response_serializer):
    argument = argument_thunk()
    if argument is not None:
        response, proceed = await _call_behavior(rpc_event, state, behavior,
                                                 argument, request_deserializer)
        if proceed:
            serialized_response = _server._serialize_response(
                rpc_event, state, response, response_serializer)
            if serialized_response is not None:
                _server._status(rpc_event, state, serialized_response)

async def _stream_response_in_pool(rpc_event, state, behavior, argument_thunk,
                                   request_deserializer, response_serializer):
    argument = argument_thunk()
    if argument is not None:
        # Notice this calls the normal `_call_behavior` not the awaitable version.
        response_iterator, proceed = _server._call_behavior(
            rpc_event, state, behavior, argument, request_deserializer)
        if proceed:
            while True:
                response, proceed = await _take_response_from_response_iterator(
                    rpc_event, state, response_iterator)
                if proceed:
                    if response is None:
                        _server._status(rpc_event, state, None)
                        break
                    else:
                        serialized_response = _server._serialize_response(
                            rpc_event, state, response, response_serializer)
                        print(response)
                        if serialized_response is not None:
                            print("Serialized Correctly")
                            proceed = _server._send_response(rpc_event, state,
                                                     serialized_response)
                            if not proceed:
                                break
                        else:
                            break
                else:
                    break

_server._unary_response_in_pool = _unary_response_in_pool
_server._stream_response_in_pool = _stream_response_in_pool


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = grpc.server(AsyncioExecutor())
    # Add Servicer and Start Server Here
```

link to original:
https://gist.github.com/seglberg/0b4487b57b4fd425c56ad72aba9971be

Comment: I fixed comment. Please remove the negative evaluation, because I think that this is a good implementation