# How to respond to client through thread - PYTHON

Tags: python, multithreading, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying (failing) to use gRPC ([grpc.io](https://grpc.io/)) with threads.

What I want that after receiving a request, scale it to a thread and respond through that thread, without the 'return' part of the gRPC.

Here is my method:

```
def CriaItem(self, request, context):
    chave = request.chave
    valor = request.valor

    validacao = self.configs.valida_chave(chave)

    if validacao[0]:
        self.queue1.enqueue((comandos['create'], chave, valor, context))
    else:
        stub = self.cria_stub(validacao[1])
        self.queue4.enqueue((comandos['create'], chave, valor, context, stub))
```

The dequeuing process will occur inside a thread. After that I want to return the some value back to the requester.

Is there a way to do that **without** using **async** keywords?

Comment: you need to show us your code .... but the answer is probably ...

Comment: I've edited. Can you help me?

Comment: Why do you need to do this without using async keyword? The typical practice for accomplishing an async response is described in Nathaniel Manista's answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38387443/how-to-implement-a-async-grpc-python-server

Comment: I needed it for an undergraduate assignment. I've managed to accomplish what I wanted.