# How can I use gRPC with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Where can I find examples of using gRPC with asyncio In particular, how to create a client using gRPC and asyncio

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 16):

As of version 1.32, gRPC now supports asyncio in its [Python API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html). If you're using an earlier version, you can still use the asyncio API via the experimental API: `from grpc.experimental import aio`. An asyncio [hello world example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld) has also been added to the gRPC repo. The following code is a copy of the example client:

```
import logging                                                                  
import asyncio                                                                  
from grpc import aio                                                            
                                                                                
import helloworld_pb2                                                           
import helloworld_pb2_grpc                                                      
                                                                                
                                                                                
async def run():                                                                
    # NOTE(gRPC Python Team): .close() is possible on a channel and should be    
    # used in circumstances in which the with statement does not fit the needs    
    # of the code.                                                              
    async with aio.insecure_channel('localhost:50051') as channel:              
        stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)                         
        response = await stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))    
    print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)                       
                                                                                
                                                                                
if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    logging.basicConfig()                                                       
    asyncio.run(run())
```

See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63020796/1510445) for how to implement the server.

Comment: It looks as though this will be moved out of "experimental" in the next release (1.32.0).

Comment: How can I use it without the "async with"?  Because I have a function, when I call this function and pass a parameter, I will send this parameter to rpc. I can not make a connect on every function call. I have to keep a connect and reuse it all the time.

Comment: @Kingname `aio.insecure_channel` just returns an `aio.Channel` object. If you look at [the docs](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html#channel-object) for `aio.Channel`, you'll see that the `async with` is not strictly necessary; all that syntax does is close the channel when the `async with` block is done. So you can make a channel with `channel = aio.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')`, you'll just have to close it yourself when you're done with `await channel.close()`.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that and code by myself. I'd like to know what will happen if I do not close this channel when I kill the process.

Comment: @Kingname It looks like `aio.Channel` doesn't handle this scenario, so I assume the connection will die when Python stops the event loop, meaning any in-flight or pending requests will be discarded. If you want to finish those requests you could write a context manager for your program that calls `close` on the channel (with a grace period) and registers your manager's `__exit__` method to be fired on the `SIGINT` signal: https://aalvarez.me/posts/gracefully-exiting-python-context-managers-on-ctrl-c/

Answer (score 2):

gRPC Python is currently not compatible with asyncio. See dicussion/feature request at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6046.

Answer (score 1):

gRPC  support for AsyncIO is now generally available, you can find the documentation here: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc_asyncio.html